# JSON.stringify() to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, json, utf-8, utf-16

Javascript uses as far as I know UTF-16 fundamentally as a standard for strings. With JSON.stringify() I can create a JSON string from an object.

**Is that JSON string UTF-16 encoded?**

**Can I convert (hopefully fast) that string to UTF-8 to save bandwidth for huge files (1MB JSON)?**

Comment: Strings aren't in UTF-8 or UTF-16 : only their binary representation resulting of an encoding is.

Comment: The assumption that utf-8 is more space efficient that utf-16 is not correct in some cases, code points above \0800 are more efficiently stored in utf-16

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [JavaScript engines are allowed to use either UCS-2 or UTF-16.](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)

So, yes, `JSON.stringify()` will return a string in whatever encoding your implementation uses for strings. If you were to find a way to change that encoding *within the context of your script*, it would no longer be a valid JavaScript string.

For serialising it over a network, though, I would expect it to automatically be transcoded into the character set of the HTTP request (assuming you're talking about HTTP). So if you send it via HTTP POST with a character set of UTF-8, your browser should transparently handle the transcoding of that data before it is sent.

Otherwise browsers would really struggle with character set handling.

Comment: +1 for "does transparently handle".  You should only ever need to specifiy an encoding when doing IO, and not tamper with it on your own.

Comment: If you happen to be using some API which deals with `Uint8Array` (raw bytes), then you can decode a UTF-8 array from a string (or in otherwords encode a string into a UTF-8 array) using `new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(JSON.stringify(object))`